# hping3 flooding makes a host unreachable permanently in mininet

Tags: ddos, mininet, pox, hping

I was simulating a DoS attack using "hping3 IP --flood" in mininet using POX controller. In my scenario, host 2 attacked host one using the mentioned command and makes the host unreachable. 
The problem is that, as I stop everything and try to ping host1, it becomes unreachable! It seems that the host becomes unreachable permanently for some reason. 
I even reboot my virtual machine and run the controller and simulator form the scratch but, again the same thing happen. Any ping attempt to host1 is unreachable.

[image]

I never seen this before, can you tell me what happen here? 
thanks